# Where to add Socket.io logic in Sailjs project

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I am new to sailjs and socket.io. I have gone through the samples in socket.io [home page](http://socket.io/#how-to-use). Now I am confused where(in which file) to write the logic of socket connected, emitting messages and chat room management in a sailjs project. Is there any clean documentation on using socket.io with sailjs.

I have seen this [tutorial](http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2013/09/06/building-a-sails-application-ep18-understanding-web-sockets-and-socket-io-including-room-creation-and-management/) but he is not demonstrated it using sailsjs, even though the subject says **Building a Sails Application: Ep18 - Understanding Web Sockets and Socket IO Including Room Creation and Management**.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: It's all [in the documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/sockets).

Answer (score 0):

You'll find all the documentation here: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/sockets

> Out of the box, Sails handles Socket.io requests the same way it handles HTTP requests-- through the Express interface. It does this by creating a fake Express request and automatically routing the socket requests to the proper controller and action. For instance, here is a simple controller:

```
// api/controllers/EchoController.js

module.exports = {
  index: function (req,res) {
    // Get the value of a parameter
    var param = req.param('message');

    // Send a JSON response
    res.json({
      success: true,
      message: param
    });
  }
};
```

**Note the file** *EchoController.js* **which in this example is where the sockets are handled.**

Comment: Suppose I need to store the client socket and implement a public chat, like when an user sends a message, I need to broadcast it to all the active sockets. Currently I don't find a proper place in sailjs  to place the code. Again thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jeevan hm, I see - in that case you might join on their [IRC channel - #sailsjs](http://webchat.freenode.net/) and ask for some help with that?

Comment: Check out http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2013/10/10/building-a-sails-application-ep21-integrating-socket-dot-io-and-sails-with-custom-controller-actions-using-real-time-model-events/ for a screencast on setting up socket.io and sails.

Comment: @vusan probably not very well - there are some serious socket issues with 0.10.0. Best to try it out yourself to find out.

Comment: @brandonscript , Can you have a look on this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129766/how-to-use-sails-io-js-version-0-11-3-in-node-server