# how to use sails.io.js version 0.11.3 in node server

Tags: node.js, sockets, sails.js, sails.io.js

I would like to create a chat application in my sailjs based project, How and where can i configure the socket and related setting in the server ? I got a sample project from this repository but it is using sails v0.10 and i need to use sails v0.11.3, but v0.11.3 having many changes while using socket in Nodejs script, for example, We can't use **onConnect** since it is deprecated.

I have tried this example, but not working this with sail v0.11.3 
https://github.com/sgress454/sailsChat

This is the code i have done, but i don't know where should i put , it is not working when i put this in sockets.js file with in the config directory

```
// Set some options:
// (you have to specify the host and port of the Sails backend when using this library from Node.js)
io.sails.url = 'http://localhost:9002';
// ...
    io.socket.on('connect', function socketConnected() {
        console.log('connect..');
    });
// Send a GET request to `http://localhost:1337/hello`:
io.socket.get('/hello', function serverResponded (body, JWR) {
  // body === JWR.body
  console.log('Sails responded with: ', body);
  console.log('with headers: ', JWR.headers);
  console.log('and with status code: ', JWR.statusCode);

  // When you are finished with `io.socket`, or any other sockets you connect manually,
  // you should make sure and disconnect them, e.g.:
  io.socket.disconnect();

  // (note that there is no callback argument to the `.disconnect` method)
});
```

Please guide me on this.

Comment: I haven't used sails.io.js, but can you try `io.socket.on('connection'..` instead of `'connect'` like normal socket.io? And do the `"Sails responded with"` messages come up?

Comment: Currently i put this in my app.js file, but 'connection' not working. Main problem is that, I don't know where should i put this code

Comment: It should go anywhere after your reference to `sails.io.js`, like this: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client/io-socket#?example ?

Comment: Ok, let me check. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been solved after using the main repository in this link

https://github.com/balderdashy/sailsChat